# Mysterious case constant defined more than once error

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor

I'm working on an embedded project using the socket library of a C language commercial RTOS.  I'm going to be super vague about some of the surrounding details for confidentiality reasons, but just know that there is a full product and RTOS stack involved.

In the part I'm working on I have a fairly large but straightforward switch statement that checks one macro value and sets another.  The case values are socket option flags from the RTOS headers.  When I compile the file with this switch statement I get an error saying "case constant defined more than once" referring to five of those cases.

Here are some details that make this mysterious:

1. All of the headers are wrapped with `#ifndef HEADER` to avoid multiple inclusions.
2. The macro values come from multiple different headers, but there is no apparent correlation between whether the case produces this error and the origin header.
3. If I comment out the single definition or don't explicitly include that header I get "undefined identifier", so it's clearly tied to that file and definition.
4. If I do a "C/C++" search for the macro in Eclipse, it lists two instances of the definition but both refer to the same spot in the same file.

I've run this by a senior developer here and he's as mystified as I am.  Does anybody know a quirk of C interpretation that could be causing this, or any landmines may have overlooked?

Thanks!

Comment: It means that after macro substitutions and expansions, there are case labels with the same integer value. Indentify the case label collissions and find out how the macros are expanded.

Comment: Without posting the code and relevant macros, we can't help you more than I did.

Comment: Confidentiality reasons are irrelevant - without a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you're not likely to get much help other than guesses.

Comment: You're being vague for confidentiality reasons.   The problem is, that makes your question so vague that nobody can sensibly help you.  Try creating an [mcve] that is unrelated to your actual "confidential" code, but exhibits the same problems.

Comment: Embarrassing as it is, I think @PaulOgilvie nailed it.  Turns out the designers of the RTOS didn't really worry too much about their parameters being used together.

Comment: Why would you ask this question without posting the switch statement and all macro definitions used?  You have chosen the least likely option ("_a quirk of C interpretation_", and asked a vague question about it.  Post the code and get a direct answer - the compiler is not wrong.  Often label "collision" is deliberate - as a means of enforcing macros are correctly defined, by failing to compile when they are not.

Comment: What it boils down to is that the problem I was having seemed mysterious due to a couple of red herrings.  Some strange IDE behavior aligned with a misinterpretation I had of an error message, which seemed to imply a weirder problem than I could capture in a few lines of code.  I can't post the actual source or recreate the file structure, so I gave a description.  Had I tried to recreate the switch statement and macros I probably could have hit on the problem, but at the time it didn't seem so localized.  Sorry to offend your sensibilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error means that the value for which the macro is substituted is the same for two or more macros, even though the macros themselves are distinct.

Here is a simple way of reproducing this error:

```
#define ONE 42
#define TWO 42

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    switch (k) {
        case ONE:
            printf("ONE\n");
            break;
        case TWO:
            printf("TWO\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("NONE\n");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even though the macros are called `ONE` and `TWO`, their values are both 42, which causes the error.

Answer (score 4):

All the references to macros and headers are (almost) besides the point: `case constant defined more than once` means that more than one of your `case` statements evaluates to the same value, so the compiler can't tell with case to choose.

Try printing out the actual values of your case labels (they should all evaluate to integers, so you can `printf` them with a `%d` format) and see if you can figure out why some of your macros have overlapping values.